# Tableau Calculation with a Filter in place

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to get the count of calls received by an individuals, both initial answer and any possible transferred over by another person.

My workbook has a filter based on the individual who first answers the phone. Now I need to add in any calls that were transferred over. These calls are usually answered by another individual.

This is what I would like to see

**John:  #calls =3 | #calls Transferred to =1**

Where the data would show this:

```
Incoming  | Transferred to
John      | James
John      | NUll
John      | NUll
James     | John
```

Does anybody have a way to get in the last call to be attribute it to John with the filter in place?
My filter of John would give me the three calls, but would remove the transferred call.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating two calculated fields using the following formulas and then use them as filters.

Filter - John

```
if contains([Incoming], "John") then "John"
ELSEif
CONTAINS([Transferred to], "John") then "John"
END
```

Filter - James

```
if contains([Incoming], "James") then "James"
ELSEif
CONTAINS([Transferred to], "James") then "James"
END
```

Comment: Same result, but more concise is just the Boolean calculation — contains([Incoming], "John") or contains([Transferred to], "John").